# navigator.share() doesn't work as expected in iOS email

Tags: ios, safari

I'm trying to implement a share button on my website, but I'm having problems with iOS Safari.

```
var title = "Subject";
var text = "Body";
var url = "https://google.com";
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: title,
    text: text,
//  url: url,
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
}
else{
    window.open("mailto:?subject="+encodeURIComponent(title)+"&body="+encodeURIComponent(text)+" "+encodeURIComponent(url), '_blank');
}
```

It works fine on android, but if I try to send an email from an iPad the subject is not set, and when I send the email the subject becomes the whole message. I suspect the iOS' mail app doesn't receive the data in the same way as the android's gmail app.

Is it a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only pass the title `navigator.share({ title, })` you'll find that in Apple's Mail, it becomes the body of the email, not the subject. This is contrary to Gmail on Android which uses the title to populate the subject.

Unfortunately, the spec [doesn't spell out](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#sharedata-dictionary) how the `title` should be used:

> *title* **member** The title of the document being shared. May be ignored by the target.

See [this article](https://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2020/04/10/web-share-api/) for more nuances and examples of `navigator.share` in iOS/Mac OS.`